# Wordpress post objects in one parent post object

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating an event page where we can add an event line-up. Such a line-up consists out of different speakers.

So I've create two custom post types:

- Line-up
- Speaker

On my event page you can select the created line-up.
A repeater is used to add speakers (speaker post objects) to a specific line-up.

On my event page:

```
<?php
   /*
    * get the ID of the selected line-up
   */

   $line_up = get_sub_field('line-up');
   $line_up_id = $line_up->ID;
?>

        

<?php
/*
 * Looping over the speakers repeater within the selected line-up
*/
if( have_rows('speakers', $line_up_id) ):
    while( have_rows('speakers') ) : the_row();
        $speaker_obj = get_sub_field('speaker_object');
        $speaker_time = get_sub_field('speaker_time');
                    
        var_dump($speaker_obj); // there is no output
                    

    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

But there is no output.

Comment: You can't use dashes in PHP variables. `$line-up` is not valid PHP. Try replacing them with underscores and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: That was a typo caused my copying it to stackoverflow. I've edited the example above.

Comment: @Dennis this is an ACF question, so it should not be asked here. And I just wanted to say that your 2nd `have_rows()` call is missing the `$line_up_id`, so that might be the cause to the issue. But if not, then you should ask on SO or an ACF support forum/site for further help/insights.